# Capturing HTTP Requests from Python Libraries not Directly Managed by User Code

Tags: python, networking, http-proxy

I'm working on a Python project where I need to inspect the HTTP requests made by my application. In my setup, I've defined my proxy environment variables in the command line as follows:

```
export http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8080
export https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

With this setup, I have been able to successfully capture HTTP requests sent by my Python program using the OpenAI library via MITMProxy. However, when I use another library, called `guidance`, which also depends on the OpenAI library, the requests are not being captured by MITMProxy.

Here is the Python code using the OpenAI library where the requests were successfully intercepted:

```py
import os
import openai

openai.api_key = os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"]

# list models
models = openai.Model.list()

# print the first model's id
print(models.data[0].id)

# create a chat completion
chat_completion = openai.ChatCompletion.create(model="gpt-3.5-turbo", messages=[{"role": "user", "content": "Hello world"}])

# print the chat completion
print(chat_completion.choices[0].message.content)
```

However, with the following code, which uses the `guidance` library, I am not able to see the requests in MITMProxy:

```py
import guidance

# set the default language model used to execute guidance programs
guidance.llm = guidance.llms.OpenAI("text-davinci-003")

# define a guidance program that adapts a proverb
program = guidance("""Tweak this proverb to apply to model instructions instead.

{{proverb}}
- {{book}} {{chapter}}:{{verse}}

UPDATED
Where there is no guidance{{gen 'rewrite' stop="\\n-"}}
- GPT {{#select 'chapter'}}9{{or}}10{{or}}11{{/select}}:{{gen 'verse'}}""")

# execute the program on a specific proverb
executed_program = program(
    proverb="Where there is no guidance, a people falls,\nbut in an abundance of counselors there is safety.",
    book="Proverbs",
    chapter=11,
    verse=14
)

print(executed_program["rewrite"]
```

I've confirmed via `pipdeptree` that the `guidance` library does indeed depend on the `openai` library. Here is the output:

```
guidance==0.0.61
  diskcache==5.6.1
  gptcache==0.1.30
    cachetools==5.3.1
    numpy==1.24.3
    requests==2.31.0
      certifi==2023.5.7
      charset-normalizer==3.1.0
      idna==3.4
      urllib3==2.0.3
  msal==1.22.0
    cryptography==41.0.1
      cffi==1.15.1
        pycparser==2.21
    PyJWT==2.7.0
    requests==2.31.0
      certifi==2023.5.7
      charset-normalizer==3.1.0
      idna==3.4
      urllib3==2.0.3
  nest-asyncio==1.5.6
  numpy==1.24.3
  openai==0.27.8
    aiohttp==3.8.4
      aiosignal==1.3.1
        frozenlist==1.3.3
      async-timeout==4.0.2
      attrs==23.1.0
      charset-normalizer==3.1.0
      frozenlist==1.3.3
      multidict==6.0.4
      yarl==1.9.2
        idna==3.4
        multidict==6.0.4
    requests==2.31.0
      certifi==2023.5.7
      charset-normalizer==3.1.0
      idna==3.4
      urllib3==2.0.3
    tqdm==4.65.0
  parsimonious==0.10.0
    regex==2023.5.5
  platformdirs==3.5.1
  pygtrie==2.5.0
  requests==2.31.0
    certifi==2023.5.7
    charset-normalizer==3.1.0
    idna==3.4
    urllib3==2.0.3
  tiktoken==0.4.0
    regex==2023.5.5
    requests==2.31.0
      certifi==2023.5.7
      charset-normalizer==3.1.0
      idna==3.4
      urllib3==2.0.3
```

Why am I unable to capture the HTTP requests from the `guidance` library even though the same method works for the `openai` library? What can I do to successfully intercept these requests? I would appreciate any insight or advice on this issue. Thank you.